# Check if an ID is in use, MySQL & PHP

Tags: php

So basically, I want to create some sort of checker in PHP that checks if an ID is in use, I have created a working system that inserts into the database, some information. I want to now check if the ID is in use because if I use the same ID to keep creating new queries or whatever you call it, it inserts it and there is more than 1 of that ID, so, is there a way somebody could please help me with this?
The table is "nameglows" and the database is called "nova" and the row is called id(lower case). Thanks!

Here is a sample of my error system:

```
// what shows up when there's an error
function error($error){
$fullerror = "<br><h1> An Error Occurred</h1><p>".$error."</p></br><h3>Click <a href=/nameglows/>here</a> to go back.</h3>";
die($fullerror);
}
//this is to check if the id is 1 or lower
if(strlen($_POST['id']) <= 1){
error('Your ID is too short! ');
}
```

There are more error codes but this is just  **1**.

Comment: Why are you not using auto-increment on an ID column in the database?

Comment: This isn't a register, this imports something inside the database for a specific paid feature in-game, I am creating a game...

Comment: This is just for now, this isn't a public release. When it does release, it willn't need a column that you have to enter your ID, it will do it on it's own. For now, I need this urgently.

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to check the ID via a MySQL query before you act, another way to deal with this is to structure your database to use a `UNIQUE` constraint when you create the MySQL table.

For example, let’s say you want to ensure that nobody is able to create a new user with the same first & last names you would create a constraint like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `unique_id_combo` UNIQUE (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`)
```

Then if someone were to—for example—register on your system with the same first & last name as someone already there, MySQL will reject the `INSERT` attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tableName` WHERE `id`=$id
```

Use the above query (ofcourse with prepered statements)

Then depending on what mysql library you're using you can do something like:

```
if(count($result) > 0) {
    //id exists
}
```

Comment: Why not count in `mysql` with `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: `if(count($result) > 0)`? You're trying to count a mysqli/PDO result set!

Comment: @worldofjr: why do you think so? And what actually confuses you there?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know why you wouldn't use `$result->num_rows` in that situation, rather than attempt to count the result set.

Comment: @worldofjr: why do you think `$result` is not a plain array with results but a resource?

Comment: @zerkms If it was an array of results then `in_array($id,$result)` would be more appropriate, don't you think? Indeed a function that returns that would be a good idea.

Comment: @worldofjr: for the query that `Barry_127` proposed - the `count($result)` is perfectly acceptable way to check the number of rows returned. Not sure why would one do `in_array` when semantically you need to count elements.